# Jquery Recursive / "InAJAXResponse" usage

Tags: jquery, ajax, recursion, levels

I'll present my problem in a topic manner bellow, tks in advance for reading!

Function:

```
$("#someAJAXContainer").load("someHTML.html");
```

Context: I want to have only one start page and then I'll add a div on the middle where all the content will be loaded dynamicly. Very similiar (if not the same) to a Master page.

```
...
<body>
<div id='menu'></div>

<div id='someAJAXContainer'></div>
<button>loadAjaxDiv</button>

<div id='footer'></div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery-ui.min.js">    </script>
<script src="functions.js></script>
</body>
...
```

The functions.js would be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#someAJAXContainer").load("someHTML.html");
   $("button").button();
   $("#responseA").click(function(event){
     alert("the link should no longer took you to jquery.com");
     event.preventDefault();
   });
 });
```

Problem: When the AJAX Response HTML is loaded on the container it's not linked to already existent JQuery code. So if the response is something like:

```
<div id ='response'>
<a id = 'responseA' href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>
</div>
```

The link will take you at the same to jquery.com page :(

So my approach to solve this is using (on the functions.js):

```
$("#someAJAXContainer").load("someHTML.html", function() {
    $("#responseA").click(function(event){
         alert("the link should no longer took you to jquery.com");
         event.preventDefault();
       });
});
```

But now I'm having multiple levels of inner ajax and it's getting a messy code! I don't like that much the way it's being worked out. So I wonder what kind of errors I might be doing here. Is this even correct at structural, good pratices, level?

Hope I been clear about the issue. I been googling about it and the only answers I've got were similiar to the one proposed before, but it was all very vague.

Regards;

Answer (score 0):

Try using [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

```
  $("#responseA").click(function(event){
     alert("the link should no longer took you to jquery.com");
     event.preventDefault();
  });
```

This will bind the click event only to #responseA element that is in the DOM at start, but wont work for any other that you load later. Live will solve this

```
  $("#responseA").live('click', function(event){
      ...
  });
```

Comment: Ok this is good for handling events. But what if I want to change properties of one element. Imagining I have one Jquery button inside the <div id='response'><buttonOK>ok</buttonOK></div> and want to do the corresponding: $("buttonOK").live().button();

Answer (score 0):

Complementing RealShadow. As I've stated in my reply you can see that `.live()` won't solve issues where one wants to change elements properties or behaviour, it only allows you to attach events listeners.

Therefore, for a situation like trying to make for a button tag to behave as button, for example:

```
<div id='response'><buttonOK>ok</buttonOK></div>
```

The solution that I found more interesting is to add an `.ajaxStop()` or `.ajaxSuccess()` event listener. It will work as a `$(document).ready(function() {})` for the AJAX calls, so all the AJAX.ready() can be setup on this. One must take into account that the identifier $("#ajaxContainer") must be pointing to the container where the HTML response is loaded so that it can find its newly generated child DOM.

```
$("#ajaxContainer").ajaxStop(function() {
        // Ajax handler called.
        $("buttonOK").button();
        });
```